# $_Cookie Issue, Access Log count is different from actual count

Tags: php, logging, cookies, httpcookie, access-log

While working with Web Development in php, I have put below check somewhere in my .php file

> AbcController.php

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['auth'])){
//server side logging code
//...some code here
```

But while `fetching the Access logs for AbcController.php with 'auth' cookie` set (grep 'auth'), the server side count is different from access logs count. 
Please help me out as this is something I'm not able to figure out.

```
(Access Log Count > Server side log count)
```

Edit: Server side logging is getting done at file level. Access logs shows cookies in headers on which we are greping.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting an `echo` statement within the block to see if the logging code is actually being accessed?

[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is used for variables, but you should use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) in order to check if `auth` is a key within the `$_COOKIE` array.

Comment: Logging is getting done both at Local & Production . But when I sent my code to production then it creates the difference in count.

Comment: Are you using different databases or tables between local and production? Can you edit your first post with more information please? I think it'd be helpful.

Comment: Is this something related to Raw Cookie ?